# Windows 10 Virtualbox on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ssh, virtualbox, windows-10, headless

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server running at my house, which replaced my windows server (as it was getting to slow). The only issue is that I have some ssh resources that require windows (and wine will not work). So, I was thinking I could set up Windows 10 in a virtualbox and route it's ssh to it's own port. I know how to set up an ssh server in a virtualbox, however since my Ubuntu Server is headless, I'm at a loss as to how to set it up.

I've been trying to search for answers, but all that comes up is running Ubuntu in a virtualbox on a Windows 10 machine, **where I want to run Windows 10 in a virtualbox on an Ubuntu Server machine.**

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm thinking I might have actually found a solution here: however I'll have to make sure everything works when I have access to the machine next week (I'm in the middle of moving). https://www.ostechnix.com/install-oracle-virtualbox-ubuntu-16-04-headless-server/

Comment: I've not done this with Windows 10, but have with Win XP and 7. Virtualbox can run in headless mode form the command line using the `vboxmanage` command. When you start the VM you must use the `--type headless` option. It is possible to configure a VRDE port for your VM, which means you can access the Windows desktop remotely via RDP.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that too. Tysm.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using those instructions as they add an outside repository to your sources file. VirtualBox is available in the default Ubuntu repositories. The `virtualbox-ext-pack` package can even take care of installing the correct extension pack for you.

Comment: duly noted, however I do like the idea of a php interface. Is that available from official repositories? I also want to point out that this is for personal use, not for a company with confidential information.

Comment: Here's [one way](https://redplus.me/post/set-up-headless-windows-10-virtual-machine-on-remote-linux-server/) one fellow did it using Vbox's built-in RDP server.

Comment: Also see [Chapter 7.1.2](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) of the Vbox manual.

Comment: @MarkDeven the VirtualBox version for Ubuntu 18.04 is 5.2 so the part of the instructions that install phpvirtualbox would be exactly applicable to the version you'd install from the official repositories. It's not included in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. Sounds like you're saying its the version that is in the repositories that isn't in the repositories.

Comment: I also would point out that PHPVirtualbox is open source and trusted :)